# How do I flash dailies without data loss?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

Is there a way to get the daily upgrades withou losing personal data i.e. my contacts and photos each times? Fyi I am doing it like this:

```
phablet-flash -l
```

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrades**

Some parts of the image can’t currently be upgraded, so it is best to deploy a full updated image. Some individual apps can be updated with apt, though. First add the phablet-team ppa (https://launchpad.net/~phablet-team/+archive/ppa) to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Then run the following command with root permissions to update apps:

```
 # apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

---

This part is from the [Ubuntu Touch release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes#Upgrades). In short, you *can* upgrade to the newest packages but sometimes when some of the Android stuff gets updated, you still need to reflash like you have been doing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should be able to use `adb pull/push` to make a backup of `/data/ubuntu/home/phablet`
or `rsync` / `scp` (if you have openssh-server installed) to make a backup of `/home/phablet` 
which you can restore after the upgrade.